# Looping over <input multiple> with FileReader only displays last image in grid of divs

Tags: javascript, html, image, input, filereader

I am trying to create a HTML form that allows the user to upload up to 5 images. After the user selects the images (from the filesystem using `<input multiple>`) I'd like to display them in 5 divs (ID'ed from #contactImage0 to #contactImage4).

To achieve this I loop over the selected images using vanilla JS and set them as background-image in the corresponding div. The problem is that only the last image in a selection actually shows up. All other divs stay empty.

After debugging a bit I found out that for all but the last image `reader.result` returns "" but I can't figure out why as the "image" variable I pass to `reader.readAsDataURL()` seems to be valid.

Why is that and how do I fix it?

```
HTML:
<div id="contactImage0" class="imagePreview"></div>
<div id="contactImage1" class="imagePreview"></div>
<div id="contactImage2" class="imagePreview"></div>
<div id="contactImage3" class="imagePreview"></div>
<div id="contactImage4" class="imagePreview"></div>
<input id="upload" type="file" onchange="LoadImage(this)" name="image" accept="image/*" multiple>

JavaScript:
function LoadImage(input){

            if (input.files.length > 5){
                alert("You may only select a maximum of 5 images!");
                // TODO: Remove selected images
                return;
            }
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
                var image = input.files[i]
                var imageDiv = 'contactImage' + i.toString();
                var element = document.getElementById(imageDiv);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(){
                    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")"; // <-- RETURNS EMPTY STRING (EXCEPT FOR LAST IMAGE)        
                }
                if(image){
                    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                    }else{
                    }
            }
        }

CSS (Shouldn't be the cause of the problem but you never know):
.imagePreview{
    margin: .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 1em);
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image:url('');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value

### Solution 1 - Creating a new function setElementBackground

```
for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
  setElementBackground(input.files[i], i);
}

function setElementBackground(file, i) {
  var image = file;
  var imageDiv = "contactImage" + i.toString();
  var element = document.getElementById(imageDiv);
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
  };
  if (image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
}
```

### Solution 2 - Using Another Closure inside for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    var count = i;
    var image = input.files[count];
    var imageDiv = "contactImage" + count.toString();
    var element = document.getElementById(imageDiv);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
    };
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  })();
}
```